# Port binding fails for script after 60 seconds when deployed to heroku

Tags: python, heroku, deployment

So I was fooling around the slack API and ended up making a simple slack bot which posts on a slack channel whether a site is up or not (when provided with the URL)

Whenever I deploy it to heroku, it works for the first 60 seconds and then throws an error like this in the logs

```
2016-06-22T20:18:11.933928+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-06-22T20:18:15.635404+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python margo/margo.py 5000`
2016-06-22T20:18:18.724727+00:00 app[web.1]: StarterBot connected and running!
2016-06-22T20:19:15.714485+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-06-22T20:19:15.714485+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-06-22T20:19:16.857081+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-06-22T20:19:16.874584+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

---

My `Procfile` looks something like this

```
web: python margo/margo.py 5000
```

I searched around and [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775527/heroku-r10-boot-timeout-error) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693192/heroku-node-js-error-web-process-failed-to-bind-to-port-within-60-seconds-of) saying that the `PORT` should be specified at the `Profile` and I changed it like the above in the `Procfile`. But mine is just a simple python script and not a full blown `Flask`/`Django` app.

Any ideas guys where am I going wrong?

**EDIT**

I read up that the `$PORT` environment variable is set by heroku. So my `Procfile` is now

```
web: python margo/margo.py $PORT
```

But the program crashes again with the same error message when deployed

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by running a simple HTTP server on the port provided by Heroku and made it run as a background process.

After the changes, my `Procfile` looks like this

```
web: (python -m http.server $PORT &) && (python margo/margo.py)
```

So, even though the web server was doing nothing, it binded itself to the port and prevented the app from crashing further.

Comment: Rather than the `&&` construct, I suggest a separate process line: `worker: python margo/margo.py`. You can then manage it explicitly via `heroku ps:start worker`.